# Do I make my COM object aggregatable or not?

Tags: visual-c++, com, atl, aggregation

I use ATL to implement a COM object. I can use one of [ATL aggregation macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb74cy5c%28VS.80%29.aspx) to change whether the object will be aggregatable. The default is "yes, it is aggregatable".

How do I decide whether I need to allow or prohibit aggregation for my COM object?

Comment: excellent question.  I believe that you would make your com object aggregatable if you intend your COM object to be used by a parent COM object (the controlling outer).  Aggregation is described as "enabling the outer object to expose another objects implementation of an interface without modification".  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3k086s0.aspx#cpconinheritanceaggregationcontainmentanchor2

Comment: @freefallr: How do I know I need it?

Comment: I normally use containment rather than aggregation.  The only time I've seen aggregation used is to wrap a singleton.

Comment: I guess its one of those options that should be turned off if you don't think you'll need it :S